# Why is my C++/CLI app unresponsive even when I've use a BackgroundWorker?

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, treeview, backgroundworker

I'm just trying to learn some Windows Forms stuff for reference, using C++/CLI. I created a project in VS 2010 called LibraryScan using the default Windows Forms options and I've modified the form with a few controls. All the code changes I've made are in Form1.h (see below). I've added the whole of Form1.h because I imagine that, if you just created a normal VS 2010 C++/CLI Windows Forms application you could replace the autogenerated Form1.h with what's below (although there is the imagelist to consider; item [0] is a generic document icon, [1] is a closed folder and [2] is an open folder).

Basically you use the "Browse..." button to select a folder, then press the "Scan" button and the aim is that it will recurse through the root folder and its subfolders to find all the files in it. The name of each file is added to a multiline TextBox, and the tree structure is generated in a TreeView.

The problem I'm having is that, without the line:

```
System::Threading::Thread::Sleep(1);
```

in the listFolder() function the UI is kind of unresponsive while scanning the folders. The TextBox gets updated ok, but the TreeView doesn't show until the scan is finished and, while scanning, you can't resize or move the application window. It's fine with the Sleep(1) in, albeit a little slow!

As I said, I'm new to Windows Forms but have some experience of MFC (although most of my 27+ years software development experience is in embedded stuff so..) including using event pumps to try to get round this sort of stuff. However the reading I've done so far seems to suggest the BackgroundWorker class and RunWorkerAsync()/ReportProgress() etc are the way to go in C++/CLI/Windows Forms but most of the questions and examples are in C# and all my searching for unresponsive guis with BackgroundWorker end up with solutions that I can't see are much different to what I'm doing!

Any help gratefully appreciated.

```
#pragma once

ref class ProgressObject;

namespace LibraryScan {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;
    using namespace System::IO;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for Form1
    /// </summary>
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~Form1()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;
    protected: 
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::FolderBrowserDialog^  folderBrowserDialog1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::OpenFileDialog^  openFileDialog1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBoxFiles;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  buttonScan;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TreeView^  treeViewFiles;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::ImageList^  imageList1;
    private: System::ComponentModel::BackgroundWorker^  fileLister;
    private: System::ComponentModel::IContainer^  components;



    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>


#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->components = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::Container());
            System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager^  resources = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager(Form1::typeid));
            this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->textBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->folderBrowserDialog1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::FolderBrowserDialog());
            this->openFileDialog1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::OpenFileDialog());
            this->textBoxFiles = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->label2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->buttonScan = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->treeViewFiles = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TreeView());
            this->imageList1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ImageList(this->components));
            this->fileLister = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::BackgroundWorker());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this->label1->AutoSize = true;
            this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(28, 13);
            this->label1->Name = L"label1";
            this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(39, 13);
            this->label1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->label1->Text = L"Folder:";
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this->textBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(74, 13);
            this->textBox1->Name = L"textBox1";
            this->textBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(409, 20);
            this->textBox1->TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(489, 13);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 2;
            this->button1->Text = L"Browse...";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button1_Click);
            // 
            // folderBrowserDialog1
            // 
            this->folderBrowserDialog1->Description = L"Select the directory that you want to scan.";
            this->folderBrowserDialog1->ShowNewFolderButton = false;
            // 
            // openFileDialog1
            // 
            this->openFileDialog1->FileName = L"openFileDialog1";
            // 
            // textBoxFiles
            // 
            this->textBoxFiles->Anchor = static_cast<System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles>(((System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Top | System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Bottom) 
                | System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Right));
            this->textBoxFiles->Location = System::Drawing::Point(34, 62);
            this->textBoxFiles->Multiline = true;
            this->textBoxFiles->Name = L"textBoxFiles";
            this->textBoxFiles->ScrollBars = System::Windows::Forms::ScrollBars::Both;
            this->textBoxFiles->Size = System::Drawing::Size(596, 419);
            this->textBoxFiles->TabIndex = 3;
            this->textBoxFiles->WordWrap = false;
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this->label2->AutoSize = true;
            this->label2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(31, 43);
            this->label2->Name = L"label2";
            this->label2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(31, 13);
            this->label2->TabIndex = 4;
            this->label2->Text = L"Files:";
            // 
            // buttonScan
            // 
            this->buttonScan->Enabled = false;
            this->buttonScan->Location = System::Drawing::Point(570, 13);
            this->buttonScan->Name = L"buttonScan";
            this->buttonScan->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
            this->buttonScan->TabIndex = 5;
            this->buttonScan->TabStop = false;
            this->buttonScan->Text = L"Scan";
            this->buttonScan->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->buttonScan->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::buttonScan_Click);
            // 
            // treeViewFiles
            // 
            this->treeViewFiles->Anchor = static_cast<System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles>(((System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Top | System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Bottom) 
                | System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Right));
            this->treeViewFiles->ImageIndex = 0;
            this->treeViewFiles->ImageList = this->imageList1;
            this->treeViewFiles->Location = System::Drawing::Point(636, 62);
            this->treeViewFiles->Name = L"treeViewFiles";
            this->treeViewFiles->SelectedImageIndex = 0;
            this->treeViewFiles->Size = System::Drawing::Size(392, 419);
            this->treeViewFiles->TabIndex = 6;
            this->treeViewFiles->AfterCollapse += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TreeViewEventHandler(this, &Form1::treeViewFiles_AfterCollapse);
            this->treeViewFiles->AfterExpand += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TreeViewEventHandler(this, &Form1::treeViewFiles_AfterExpand);
            // 
            // imageList1
            // 
            this->imageList1->ImageStream = (cli::safe_cast<System::Windows::Forms::ImageListStreamer^  >(resources->GetObject(L"imageList1.ImageStream")));
            this->imageList1->TransparentColor = System::Drawing::Color::Transparent;
            this->imageList1->Images->SetKeyName(0, L"Generic_Document.png");
            this->imageList1->Images->SetKeyName(1, L"Folder_16x16.png");
            this->imageList1->Images->SetKeyName(2, L"FolderOpen_16x16_72.png");
            // 
            // fileLister
            // 
            this->fileLister->WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            this->fileLister->DoWork += gcnew System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventHandler(this, &Form1::fileLister_DoWork);
            this->fileLister->ProgressChanged += gcnew System::ComponentModel::ProgressChangedEventHandler(this, &Form1::fileLister_ProgressChanged);
            this->fileLister->RunWorkerCompleted += gcnew System::ComponentModel::RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(this, &Form1::fileLister_RunWorkerCompleted);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(1040, 493);
            this->Controls->Add(this->treeViewFiles);
            this->Controls->Add(this->buttonScan);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBoxFiles);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
            this->Name = L"Form1";
            this->Text = L"Form1";
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
             {
                 // Show the FolderBrowserDialog.
                 System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1->ShowDialog();
                 if ( result == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK )
                 {
                     String^ folderName = folderBrowserDialog1->SelectedPath;
                     textBox1->Text = folderName;
                     buttonScan->Enabled = true;
                 }
             }

    private: System::Void buttonScan_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
             {
                 // Scan the folder listed in textBox1 and add the files to textBoxFiles
                 String^ folder = textBox1->Text;
                 fileLister->RunWorkerAsync(folder);
             }

    private: long listFolder(String^ folderName, TreeNode^ rootNode, BackgroundWorker^ worker)
             {
                 // Scan the folder passed in and add the files to textBoxFiles
                 TreeNode^ newNode = gcnew TreeNode(folderName);
                 newNode->ImageIndex = 1;
                 newNode->SelectedImageIndex = 1;
                 worker->ReportProgress(0, gcnew ProgressObject(rootNode, newNode));

                 array<String^>^ file = Directory::GetFiles( folderName );
                 Array::Sort(file);
                 for (int i = 0; i < file->Length; i++)
                 {
                     TreeNode^ fileNode = gcnew TreeNode(file[i]);
                     worker->ReportProgress(0, gcnew ProgressObject(newNode, fileNode));
                     System::Threading::Thread::Sleep(1);
                 }

                 // Now scan the directories under this one
                 array<String^>^ dir = Directory::GetDirectories(folderName);
                 Array::Sort(dir);
                 for (int i = 0; i < dir->Length; i++)
                 {
                     listFolder(dir[i], newNode, worker);
                 }

                 return 0L;
             }

private: System::Void treeViewFiles_AfterCollapse(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::TreeViewEventArgs^  e)
         {
             e->Node->ImageIndex = 1;
             e->Node->SelectedImageIndex = 1;
         }

private: System::Void treeViewFiles_AfterExpand(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::TreeViewEventArgs^  e) 
         {
             e->Node->ImageIndex = 2;
             e->Node->SelectedImageIndex = 2;
         }
private: System::Void fileLister_DoWork(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventArgs^  e)
         {
             BackgroundWorker^ worker = dynamic_cast<BackgroundWorker^>(sender);
             e->Result = listFolder(safe_cast<String^>(e->Argument), nullptr, worker);
         }
private: System::Void fileLister_ProgressChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::ProgressChangedEventArgs^  e)
         {
             ProgressObject^ prog = safe_cast<ProgressObject^>(e->UserState);
             if (prog->currentNode != nullptr)
             {
                if (prog->rootNode == nullptr)
                {
                    treeViewFiles->Nodes->Add(prog->currentNode);
                }
                else
                {
                    prog->rootNode->Nodes->Add(prog->currentNode);
                }
                textBoxFiles->AppendText(String::Concat(prog->currentNode->Text, "\n"));
             }
         }

private: System::Void fileLister_RunWorkerCompleted(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs^  e)
         {
             this->textBoxFiles->AppendText(L"Scan Complete");
         }

    ref class ProgressObject : public Object
    {
    public:
        TreeNode^ rootNode;
        TreeNode^ currentNode;

        ProgressObject(TreeNode^ theRootNode, TreeNode^ theCurrentNode)
            : rootNode(theRootNode),
              currentNode(theCurrentNode)
        {
        }
    };
};
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program suffers from the 3rd most common threading bug.  Numbers 1 and 2 are threading races and deadlock, BackgroundWorker is pretty good at helping you avoid those nasty ones.  But it doesn't do anything to help you avoid number 3, a *fire-hose bug*.  Mental image here is trying to drink from a running fire-hose, no matter how hard you swallow you can never avoid spilling water.

The water here are the TreeNodes that the worker produces.  Your file system is fast and can spit them out at a very high rate.  Especially so the second time you run your program and all the file data comes from the file system cache.  Tens of thousands per second.

The mouth is the UI thread in your program, it needs to add these nodes to the TreeView and generates a paint to make them visible.   At best it can add hundreds per second.

The UI thread starts dispatching the invoke request as soon as your worker first calls ReportProgress().  It executes the request by calling your ProgressChanged event handler.  Problem is, as soon as that is done, there's yet another invoke request waiting.  It can never catch up and get the invoke queue emptied.  It burns 100% core, doing nothing but calling your ProgressChanged event handler.

And stops doing its normal duty, dispatching operating system notifications.  Which includes input, you see that it is no longer responsive to mouse clicks and keyboard input.  And painting, a low priority task that only gets performed when nothing else needs to be done.

It is *not* deadlocked or frozen, you'll see it come back alive as soon as your worker thread completes.  Usually several seconds after the worker is done, it still needs to work down the backlog of invoke requests that are in the queue.  And it works when you turn down the fire-hose, slowing down the worker with Thread.Sleep() so you can swallow fast enough.

You'll need more than one workaround to keep the threads balanced:

- Don't call ReportProgress() so often, collect nodes in a `List<TreeNode^>^` until you have, say, a hundred of them.  Keep thread-safety in mind, you have to create a new List after the ReportProgress() call.
- Use the TreeView.Items.AddRange() method in your ProgressChanged event handler, much more efficient than adding them one at a time.
- Avoid TreeView doing too much work to get the nodes painted, call its BeginUpdate() method when you start the worker, EndUpdate() in your RunWorkerCompleted event handler.  You'll miss out on the "live" update that way but that's of little concern, the user doesn't stand any chance to read them that fast anyway.
- Consider not updating the TreeView at all until the worker is done, given that the live view isn't very interesting anyway.  Do so in the RunWorkerCompleted event handler.

Comment: Thanks for that Hans; since I asked the question I'd been homing in on there being too many progress updates so I've been looking at trying to reduce them. The thing that seemed odd to me though was that the TextBox was getting updated without any problems and the TreeView wasn't! I'll take a look at your helpful suggestions and see how it goes. It doesn't help that the PC I was working on isn't connected to the internet, and Intellisense doesn't work :-)